# Is it necessary to stop Guice Persist Service?

Tags: jpa, guice

I don't see any difference in my code if I shut it down or not. Is it a mere practice to shut it down or am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

What is 'a mere practice'?

The javadoc of `PersistService.stop()` states that the method:

> Stops the underlying persistence engine. For instance, with JPA, it closes the EntityManagerFactory.

Which means you absolutely should call it, as `EntityManagerFactory` should definitely be notified to relinquish any resources it may be holding (DB connection pool and the like).